# Getting warning in Security Hotspot in SonarQube make sure that controlled safely here

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, sonarqube

```
    ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
```

Controlling permissions is security-sensitive. It has led in the past to the following vulnerabilities:

```
 CVE-2018-12999
 CVE-2018-10285
 CVE-2017-7455
```

and the suggestion is this.
class SecurityPrincipalDemo
{
class MyIdentity : IIdentity // Sensitive, custom IIdentity implementations should be reviewed
{
// ...
}

```
class MyPrincipal : IPrincipal // Sensitive, custom IPrincipal implementations should be reviewed
{
    // ...
}
[System.Security.Permissions.PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "Administrators")] // Sensitive. The access restrictions enforced by this attribute should be reviewed.
static void CheckAdministrator()
{
    WindowsIdentity MyIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent(); // Sensitive
    HttpContext.User = ...; // Sensitive: review all reference (set and get) to System.Web HttpContext.User
    AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
    domain.SetPrincipalPolicy(PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal); // Sensitive
    MyIdentity identity = new MyIdentity(); // Sensitive
    MyPrincipal MyPrincipal = new MyPrincipal(MyIdentity); // Sensitive
    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = MyPrincipal; // Sensitive
    domain.SetThreadPrincipal(MyPrincipal); // Sensitive

    // All instantiation of PrincipalPermission should be reviewed.
    PrincipalPermission principalPerm = new PrincipalPermission(null, "Administrators"); // Sensitive
    principalPerm.Demand();

    SecurityTokenHandler handler = ...;
    // Sensitive: this creates an identity.
    ReadOnlyCollection<ClaimsIdentity> identities = handler.ValidateToken(…);
}

 // Sensitive: review how this function uses the identity and principal.
void modifyPrincipal(MyIdentity identity, MyPrincipal principal)
{
    // ...
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

never mind. i figure it out by delacraing private read only

Answer (score -1):

[Sonar](https://rules.sonarsource.com/csharp/type/Security%20Hotspot/RSPEC-4834/)

First of all let me clarify that a Security Hotspot is not equivalent to an “Error”. This is actually an area in your code to which we want to bring your attention due a potential security threat and ask you to manually review it since SonarQube cannot solely decide whether this is an actual real threat in your context or not.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34993850)